# How can I change the headers of the <video> tag so that when rewinding the video itself, chunks are requested only from the desired part of the video?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, xmlhttprequest, video-streaming, html5-video

I stream the video from the server, send it in chunks, everything generally works, but if I rewind the video, say, to the middle, then there is a request to download all the chunks up to THIS part that I rewound to. Is it possible to change the range query from  or are there any other options?

**Client:**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import viteLogo from "/vite.svg";
import axios from "axios";
import Player from "./PLayer";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const uploadVideo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/upload");
    setVideoUrl("http://localhost:3000/video");
  };
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(videoRef.current.buffered);
  }, [videoUrl]);
  return (
    <>
      <video controls width="500" ref={videoRef} preload="auto">
        {videoUrl ? <source src={videoUrl} /> : ""}
        Ваш браузер не поддерживает воспроизведение видео.
      </video>
      <button onClick={(e) => uploadVideo(e)}>Начать загрузку</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Server:**

```
import express from "express";
import WebTorrent from "./index.js";
import cors from "cors";
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
console.log(WebTorrent);
const client = new WebTorrent();
const torrentId =
  "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:b11a75295cf2f3a230adf5226f70675f06cee2ff&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopentor.net%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openbittorrent.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopentracker.i2p.rocks%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fatrack.pow7.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fpow7.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fsecure.pow7.com%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ft1.pow7.com%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ft2.pow7.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.bittor.pw%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Ftracker.dler.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbt2.t-ru.org%2Fann%3Fmagnet";
app.get("/upload", (req, res) => {
  client.add(torrentId, (torrent) => {
    console.log(1);
    // torrent.on("download", () => {
    //   console.log(torrent.progress);
    // });
    res.send("ok");
  });
});

app.get("/video", (req, res) => {
  const range = req.headers.range;
  const file = client.get(torrentId).files[0];
  const startParsed = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
  const start = parseInt(startParsed);
  const chunksize = 12 ** 6;
  const end = Math.min(start + chunksize, file.length - 1);
  console.log(start, end, chunksize, file.length);
  const head = {
    "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${file.length}`,
    "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
    "Content-Length": chunksize + 1,
    "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
  };
  res.writeHead(206, head);
  const stream = file.createReadStream({
    start: start,
    end: end,
  });
  stream.pipe(res);
  stream.on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Error in stream:", err);
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

I tried to refer to the buffered attribute , but for some reason everything is always zero, start is empty, nothing changes. The start range is displayed normally on the server.